# distributive law with vectors

Tags: vectors

Given that $\begin{bmatrix}3 \\4 \\0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{align}
\vec{\bf a}\cdot {\big(\vec{\bf a} + \, \vec{\bf b} \big)} &= 7
\end{align}$ what is the value of $a\cdot b$

I would have thought because

$|a| = 5$

And using the distributive law:

$a.(a + b)$

=> $a^2 + ab = 7$

=> $ab = \frac{7}{a^2}$

=> $b = \frac{7}{a}$

=> $b = \frac{7}{5}$

=> $a.b = \frac{35}{5}$

=> 7

Comment: Your step is wrong it should be $b=7/a^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE**: You are dealing with vectors here where dot product is defined as:$$\vec{a}.\vec{b}=|a|.|b|.\cos{\theta}$$where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.

So, you were right in stating that:$$\vec{a}.\vec{a}=|a|.|a|.\cos(0)=|a|^2$$however:$$\vec{a}.\vec{b}\ne|a|.|b|$$The correct steps would be:$$\begin{align}
\vec{a}.(\vec{a}+\vec{b})&=\vec{a}.\vec{a}+\vec{a}.\vec{b}\\
&=|a|^2+\vec{a}.\vec{b}\\
\therefore \vec{a}.\vec{b}&=\vec{a}.(\vec{a}+\vec{b})-|a|^2\\
&=7-25\\
&=-18
\end{align}$$

Comment: I confused to what $\vec{a}$ actually means, I take it is not the component form.  I mean is it a scalar value and if so how is it obtaned?

Comment: $\vec{a}$ means the **vector** $a$ - it has components in each of the spatial dimensions. In your question the **vector** $a$ has a magnitude of $3$ in the $x$ direction, $4$ in the $y$ direction, and $0$ in the $z$ direction.

Comment: I'm still confused by this, does $\vec{a}.\vec{a} = |a^2|$

Comment: Yes it is. You may want to review vectors by looking [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors.html)